# Sample size and statistical significance dicussion

Tags: econometrics

As we know, sample size can play a role in reaching statistical significance, provided that splitting the quant world in what is and what is not statistically significant is probably an overestimated/oversold approach.

My friend sends me a [link](https://www.amstat.org/asa/files/pdfs/p-valuestatement.pdf) and saying that from this document, we can conclude that "**laws effect on different settings with different sizes is simply a matter of fact**".

I read this short document but still cannot understand how to reach this conclusion. What I am doing is to try to address [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/45888/what-we-should-do-when-the-result-is-only-significant-to-one-country-but-the-who). Simply speaking, the significant level are different between international sample and non-US sample.